# How to run scripts in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have the following scripts, which can be run in Sublime text built-in build.

I want to know how to run the `sample script` in command line

like `mongo -f sample_script.js`, thanks

### sample_script.js

```
use security_development;

Object.bsonsize(db.grouped.findOne({"_id":"00063acf1078671c6b90d46effad474b"}))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run javascript script (.js file) in mongodb including another file inside js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248730/run-javascript-script-js-file-in-mongodb-including-another-file-inside-js)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `-f`. Move database selection to command-line argument, though (`use` and `show` helpers don't work when executed from a file)

```
mongo -d security_development sample_script.js
```