# How to delete documents returned by an aggregation query in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am attempting to delete all the documents returned by an aggregation in Mongodb.

The query I have is as follows:

```
db.getCollection("Collection")
  .aggregate([
    {
      $match: { status: { $in: ["inserted", "done", "duplicated", "error"] } }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } }
      }
    },  
    { $match: { yearMonthDay: { $eq: "2019-08-06" } } }
  ])
  .forEach(function(doc) {
    db.getCollection("Collection").remove({});
  });
```

I tried this query but it removes all the data in the database, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since the **remove** doesn't have a query condition its going to match with all the documents and delete irrespective of the aggregation result.

**Solution** (match the ids of the current cursor doc):

```
db.getCollection("Collection")
  .aggregate([
    {
      $match: { status: { $in: ["inserted", "done", "duplicated", "error"] } }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } }
      }
    },
    { $match: { yearMonthDay: { $eq: "2019-08-06" } } }
  ])
  .forEach(function(doc) {
    db.getCollection("Collection").remove({ "_id": doc._id });
  });
```

Another **better solution** would be to have single round trip to db while deletion is get a list of ids from the aggregation [**`cursor()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) via [**`cursor.map()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/#cursor.map)

```
var idsList = db
  .getCollection("Collection")
  .aggregate([
    {
      $match: { status: { $in: ["inserted", "done", "duplicated", "error"] } }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } }
      }
    },
    { $match: { yearMonthDay: { $eq: "2019-08-06" } } }
  ])
  .map(function(d) {
    return d._id;
  });

//now delete those documents via $in operator
db.getCollection("Collection").remove({ _id: { $in: idsList } });
```

Comment: Thanks for nswer, I will try that then i get u back

Comment: Thnaks it works I have another question please, I can execute the second one using a js file ?

Comment: Yes it'll work in the shell as well as in a js file.

Comment: thanks, but I will have to mention the connectionstring to mongo or I put just this code ?

Comment: U can [execute a js file directly from the mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#execute-a-javascript-file) but I sense that's not what u'are looking for, and probably u want this code to run in node.js or something.. then yes connection string and collection instance and all that is required. [link](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/)

Comment: I want to execut it in linux script, it gives somme error :2019-11-06T14:33:53.151+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' @(shell):1:0

Comment: look i created two files, file.js where I put your second suggestion and a script.sh contains mongo < file.js  my quetion is ; I have to mention the ConnectionString in js file ??

Comment: Are you trying the first method -> executing a js file in mongo shell If yes, [This has some detailed info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248730/run-javascript-script-js-file-in-mongodb-including-another-file-inside-js). Also its not entirely clear from the error.. Would suggested to ask a another self contained question to reach better visibility & help.

Comment: does the better solution work if the idsList is very large (millions of records)? What is the disadvantage of the first solution?

Comment: @rcs I believe even if the idList is very large the single round trip query would be faster because `_id` is an indexed field, even though I don't have any benchmark. When compared to doing million IO for each `_id`. Also the "better solution" should only make a difference when the number of ids returned are very large.

Comment: After `.map(d => d._id)` it was necessary to chain it with `.toArray()`, otherwise it's still a cursor and not collected into an array.

Answer (score 5):

As per your query its not required to filter by aggregation and remove by another methods, you can apply this query filters in [remove()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/#remove-all-documents-from-a-collection) method's filters,

- the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) Allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language,

```
db.getCollection("Collection").remove({ 
  $and: [
    { status: { $in: ["inserted", "done", "duplicated", "error"] } },
    {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } },
          "2019-08-06"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

This can also support in [deleteOne](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/) and [deleteMany](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/) methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `expires` to your document, and update this field in the `$merge` stage of your aggregation.

```
// 1) add this to your schema
deleteAt: {
  type: Date,
  expires: 0,
}

// 2) set the value of `deleteAt` for the documents to be deleted

// 3) add this at the end of the aggregation 
$merge: {
  into: "Collections" // or "Collection"
}
```