# Mongodb aggregation lookup with condition

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nonsequential

I have two collections called 'store' and 'items' , where store keep all product records belongs to the supermarket with timestamp. And 'items' keeps records of some details about purchases.

**Store Collection**

```
{{"id": "802736816700002577966429","$date": "2021-05-05T07:02:51Z","state":"VALID"},{"id": "802736816700002577966430","$date": "2021-07-27T07:02:51Z","state":"NOT VALID"},{"id": "802736816700002577966430","$date": "2021-04-27T07:02:51Z","state":"VALID"}}
```

**Item Collection**

```
{{"id": "802736816700002577966429","$date": "2021-05-05T07:02:51Z"},{"id": "802736816700002577966430","$date": "2021-07-27T07:02:51Z"},{"id": "802736816700002577966430","$date": "2021-07-27T07:02:51Z"}}
```

The query which i want to execute is ->

> Select items from **Store Collection** where state != VALID and timestamp<2021-05-10 and then delete corresponding items from **Item Collection**

Please provide Spring-boot criteria/aggregation code which is similar to

> Criteria criteriaEvt = new Criteria(....);
>
> Aggregation aggregationEvt = newAggregation(.....)

Comment: You need to do it in 2 queries. In the first query you find the "corresponding items" ($lookup with sub-query) and then remove them `db.item.remove({_id:{$in:[id1, id2, ..., idn]}})`

Comment: Run this query [https://mongoplayground.net/p/R2poC_iSypY](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R2poC_iSypY) and remove 1 by 1 o remove with `$in` expression https://stackoverflow.com/a/58730480/3710490