# How to Data purge in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

I have to purge data older then 6 months from "transactions" collection and this purged data have to store in my "transactions_archive" collection, so plz suggest to write the script

Answer (score 0):

Use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) , then remove data from `transactions`

```
db.getCollection('transactions').aggregate([
    { $merge: {
         into: "transactions_archive"
    } }
])
```

Comment: With this all records inserted into "transactions_archive" collection. But I want to insert only older then 6 months records in this table on the bases of "trans_datetime" field. And then will delete these records from "transactions" collection.

Comment: @PradipKumar You can just add $match condition before merge unless you don't know how to use $match. Then if you want to delete, you can try this [delete-documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729824/how-to-delete-documents-returned-by-an-aggregation-query-in-mongodb?noredirect=1&lq=10)