# How to remote connect to a mongo DB which sits on top of K8S

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongodb-query

Currently I am working on a task to populate some data into a mongo DB. This mongo DB is built on top of K8S as follows. This is the first time I am working in such environment.
[image]

As you can see, on the "Shell" level, I was able to run

```
mongo -u root -p
```

to manually get into the mongo console page, and manually worked on the rest of DB queries.

But my question is, at the same "Shell" level, can I have all queries wrapped in a JS file and with a remote DB connection string to have it executed ?

Here is a sample of my read.js file I have tried:

```
var db = connect('127.0.0.1:27017/fext'),
    allDevices = null;

allDevices = db.names.find();

//iterate the names collection and output each document
while (allDevices.hasNext()) {
    printjson(allDevices.next());
}
```

And when I was to have it executed in this command:

```
mongo read.js -u root -p
```

I have got following returning message:
[image]

Comments ?  Thanks for the help !

Jack

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248730) your question?

Comment: it works, if I manually login mongo db and run "load()" to execute the remaining queries in that js file.  But it does not work if I was to run "mongo localhost:27017/fext read.js" in one shot.